# Processing multidimensional array - PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've got this cycle:

```
   $diffe = $differenz*7;  
    $diff = 0; 
    $n = 0;
    $an = $anzahl-1;
    $z = 0;
    $plus = $periode;
    $oarray = array();
    $sarray = array();
    $parray = array();
    $h = 0;

    while ($n < $ortcount) {
    foreach ($ortearray as $o) {
    $oarray[] = $o;
    }
    $sarray[] = get_start_dates($star, $diff, $wochearray); 
    $diff += $diffe;

    while ($h < $ortcount) {
    $helpingstring= join(";",$sarray[$h]);
    echo $h;
    $sarrayhelp = explode(";", $helpingstring);

    while ($z < $an) {

    foreach ($sarrayhelp as $s) {         
    $parray[] = plustime($s, $plus);        

    }
    $plus = $plus+$periode;
    $z++;

    }
    $h++;
    }

    $n++;

    }
```

and need the following:

every "subarray" of the multidimensional array "$sarray[]" should be  progressively processed by the 
plustime() function and results should be saved to "$parray[]".

At this time, only the first subarray of  "$sarray[]" is being processed.

Any help would be greately appreciated. 
Please help!

Comment: I think the first step is that you learn how to properly indent code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make recursive function:

```
function process(&$parray, $array, $plus){
  foreach($array as $s) {
    if(is_array($s)) {
      // this is subarray
      process($parray, $s, $plus);
      continue ;
    }
    $parray[] = plustime($s, $plus);
  }
}

.....
while ($z < $an) {
  process($parray, $sarrayhelp, $plus);
  ..
```

Please mind, bad indent and short variables (`$a, $az,$n, $an, $h, $z, $parray, $oarray, $diff, $diffe`) makes your code very to difficult maintance and understand by others.

Comment: Oh, yes! That's it. Thanks very much. Sorry, I am a beginner and perhaps I also made the ident worse when copying the code to this forum.